# What is the best way to design a client API?

Tags: api

I often have to design client APIs for use by other programmers. The language can vary from Ruby, Java, Erlang and Javascript (Mootools). Does anyone have any tips on creating a very usable API. And yes, this "is" a very subjective question and I am asking so that I can make my APIs easier to use by others.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469161/how-do-you-define-a-good-or-bad-api

Comment: Thanks, when I entered the question I did not see the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend to follow [Joshua Bloch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch)'s advice: [Joshua Bloch - How to Design a Good API and Why it Matters](http://www.google.com/search?q=Joshua+Bloch+-+How+To+Design+a+Good+API+and+Why+It+Matters). It's available in [PDF](http://fwdinnovations.net/whitepaper/APIDesign.pdf) and [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAb7hSCtvGw).

Answer (score 2):

If you have are interested in some non-free alternatives, then the following book would be a good recommendation:

[Practical API Design: Confessions of a Java Framework Architect by Jaroslav Tulach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430209739)

Answer (score 1):

watch this:
http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-3733345136856180693#

To add details this is a video of lecture given by Josh Bloch who's a senior java bod at Google. It's excellent if you want an overview on issues to consider when making an API

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas:

- Make your method names very descriptive
- Use documentation to clearly indicate parameters and return values
- Follow YAGNI and KISS
- Nothing helps like code examples... lots of them covering lots of use cases

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading the following from the Trolltech/Nokia guys:

**[The Little Manual of API Design](http://www4.in.tum.de/~blanchet/api-design.pdf)**

Answer (score 1):

If one of your primary goals is to make an *usable* API, or, in other words, to provide good *developer experience*, then maybe you should review this list of resources (api usability & developer experience resources): http://www.apiusabilitytesting.com/resources/