# What language to choose for SaaS API?

Tags: api, user-interface, programming-languages, saas

I work in a small organization that has built an enterprise SaaS solution.  Up until this point our workflows have had no programmatic interface.  We're moving to a model that will allow for an end user to do anything programmatically that can be done in the UI.  I'm looking for suggestions in terms of the language/framework that you would use to build that programmatic layer.

From an organizational perspective I would like the current UI team to also have ownership of the API.  That team is familiar with PHP, Rails, and Javascript.  Our current back-end code is written in Scala.  I'm leaning toward not doing the APIs in Scala because it doesn't seem like the right tool for the job and the lack of subject matter expertise around it on the UI team.

From a functionality perspective most of the APIs will be fairly simple database operations (CRUD) with perhaps some simplistic business logic applied on top (search for example).

I'm a bit intrigued by using Node.js for this as everyone on the team is really strong with Javascript.  That being said I don't just want to hop on the semi-new technology bandwagon.  Because it is enterprise software, unit testing frameworks, reusability, and extendability are all important considerations as well.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question was about technology options, but there's a fundamental concern that seems really important to call out:

> From an organizational perspective I would like the current UI team to also have ownership of the API.

While this sounds like a logical approach, it may not work out well unless you're UI team is made up of really solid engineers. SaaS API development is arguably one of the most challenging aspects of modern software design. A great API will make everyone's lives easier, while a poor API will bring your system to its knees and leave you completely clueless as to why.

As a quick example, if you don't solve the end user's needs in the right way, you're likely to force a number of [n+1 problems](http://ayende.com/blog/3732/solving-the-select-n-1-problem) on them (and thus, on you.)

There is a bunch of great material out there about [how to design great APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/469193/51055) and even more about the pitfalls of designing a bad one. Generally speaking, most of the UI devs I've worked with, particularly ones that are only familiar with scripting languages, are not people I would entrust to API design. Instead I would utilize them as customers (in a Scrum sense) who guide the design by describing end-user needs.

Answer (score 1):

I faced something like this on a previous project, where we ended up going with a combo of [Esper](http://esper.codehaus.org/) and our own DSL written using [ANTLR 3.0](http://www.antlr3.org/).   Our biggest concern with using a fully funcional runtime, was sandboxing the user's code.

That said, I think Node.JS would be one of the easier ones to sandbox and it fits your needs.  Maybe using something like this: http://gf3.github.com/sandbox/ or looking into [Cloud9's code](https://github.com/ajaxorg) to see how they keep things safe.   I also like that with Node.js you could give your users a pretty niffy editor using [Ace](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace).

Also check out this post: [How to run user-submitted scripts securely in a node.js sandbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446729/how-to-run-user-submitted-scripts-securely-in-a-node-js-sandbox)